# ng-click - hide all other div that isn't this $index within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, ng-hide

What i'm trying to do is similiar to an accordion.

Simple put 
i have an ng-repeat with an `<a>` tag that once clicked show another div called **"Printpanel"** nested inside it within **ng-show**.

If the user cick to another `<a>` tag, i want to hide all other div showed before, and open only to that one related.

I am using $index to trigger the specific div.

Here what i have done:

```
 <div ng-repeat="product in $ctrl.Products">
    <a href="#" ng-click="showDetails = $index;>CONFIGURE</a>


 <div class="Printpanel ng-hide" ng-show="showDetails == $index" ng-hide="showDetails != $index">
 </div>
```

it seems that ng-hide is not recognized... Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` also:

```
<div class="Printpanel" ng-if="showDetails == $index">
```

EDIT:

due to scope inheritance problem, you are not able to set `showDetails` variable. use `$parent` for that.

working example:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in $ctrl.Products">
    <a href="#" ng-click="$parent.showDetails = $index">CONFIGURE</a>
    <div class="Printpanel" ng-if="$parent.showDetails == $index"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't know... i upvote, anyway thank you for advice, but the problem still remain, i want to remove all others div showed

Comment: This is a problem of angular scope inheritance, use as controller as notation. and use their view modal object to access `showDetails` variable.

Comment: If you don;t want to use as notation, then as an alternate; you can use $parent to access `showDetails` variable of parent scope.

Comment: @PdsInk "*It is always better to use ng-if*" is wrong. In this case, ngShow is clearly better as it won't force to delete/add elements to the DOM when clicking a link. I guess that is why your answer has been downvoted, Sachin.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `ngShow` + `ngHide`: one is enough.

```
 <div class="Printpanel ng-hide" ng-show="showDetails == $index">
```

Comment: ok, thank you, i was only trying to figure out.
But my problem still remain, all other Printpanel divs are still visible

Answer (score 0):

seems you have missed closing double quotes here ng-click="showDetails = $index;

Also either of one you need to use ng-show/ng-hide/ng-if = expression